# Recyclerview Alphabetical Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I need to implement a recyclerview alphabetical scrollbar similar to Samsung Music app (I can't post the image because of low reputation)

I have read all posts regarding this, but I don't want the bubble scroll. I have all the alphabets in a vertical LinearLayout, and I want to know how to scroll to the particular item.

Comment: perfect question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView). To get more information checkout the [README](https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView/blob/master/README.md)

[image]

**Step 1**: add the dependecies

In build.gradle (Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

In app gradle

```
dependencies {
    // AppCompat version
       implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.92'
    or
    // AndroidX version
       implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.94'
}
```

**Step 2**: Add the layout

```xml
<in.myinnos.alphabetsindexfastscrollrecycler.IndexFastScrollRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fast_scroller_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Step 2**: implement SectionIndexer to RecyclerViewAdapter.

```java
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> implements SectionIndexer {

private List<String> mDataArray;
private ArrayList<Integer> mSectionPositions;

.....

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    List<String> sections = new ArrayList<>(26);
    mSectionPositions = new ArrayList<>(26);
    for (int i = 0, size = mDataArray.size(); i < size; i++) {
        String section = String.valueOf(mDataArray.get(i).charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
        if (!sections.contains(section)) {
            sections.add(section);
            mSectionPositions.add(i);
        }
    }
    return sections.toArray(new String[0]);
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
    return mSectionPositions.get(sectionIndex);
}

}
```

If it's hard to figure out thing, have a look at the sample [app](https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main)

Comment: Thank you, will check it out

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Something wrong with the library. fails to resolve during build gradle.